# Polymer core-item selected issue

Tags: polymer, web-component

Code can be found here: https://ele.io/MikeFielden/cw-style-demo-menu

What Im trying to achieve here is to have a left nav component that I can include on many pages with an `attribute` on the tag selected that I can use to key off of and select the corresponding `core-item`.

For the life of me I cannot get it working. I guess I'm confused about piercing the shadow DOM from within js? Not really sure what the best approach here is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

The whole menu template should look like (note the setting of `selected` attribute on `paper-item`):

```
<core-menu id="nav">
  <template repeat='{{node in nodes}}'>
    <paper-item id="{{node.name | lowercase}}" selected='{{selected == node.name}}'>
      <a href="{{node.location}}" tabindex="-1">{{node.name}}</a>
    </paper-item>
  </template>
</core-menu>
```

I did not get why you needed two nested templates, so I simplified things a bit. Now the only thing left to do is to set the `selected` attribute of your demo menu to the proper name (`id` is not needed at all, it’s fine comparing items by names):

```
<cw-style-demo-menu selected="Assets">
```

Full live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/E2B94tfAhJXnPZrusjtz?p=preview

Comment: Dude. I dont know why I nested them either. Probably making it harder than it needed to be :) Thanks.